# Custom Editor Template not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, mvc-editor-templates

I have collection of models. For each item from that collection i need to render some html form. So i decide to create editor template for this model.

This is like i "call" my editor template.

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.SpaceImages.Count; i++)
                           { %>
                        <% Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpaceImages[i]); %>
                        <% } %>
```

And this is my template :

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Models.Application.ListingSpaceAttachmentModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Web.Extensions" %>

<div id="SpaceImagesControl" class="attachment-upload-control">
    <input type="hidden" class="attachment-type" value="image" />
    <input type="hidden" class="is-dynamic-attachment-list" value="true" />
    <div class="form-field uploader-field">
        <div id="listingSpaceImagesUploader" class="attachment-uploader" style="margin-left: 60px;">
            <button class="upload-btn btn-sm"><strong>Add</strong></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uploader-data-section">
        <input class="base-attachment-src" type="hidden" />
        <input class="base-preview-attachment-src" type="hidden" />
        <input class="attachment-src" type="hidden" />
        <input class="img-width" type="hidden" />
        <input class="img-height" type="hidden" />
        <input class="img-ratio" type="hidden" />
    </div>
    <div class="attachment-data-section">
        <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentId) %>
        <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentType) %>
        <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrdinalNumber) %>
        <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentTitle, new {@class="attachment-title-input"}) %>
        <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentPath, new {@class="attachment-input"}) %>
        <%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AttachmentOriginalPath, new {@class="attachment-original-input"}) %>
    </div>
    <div class="attachment-container-template" style="display: none;">

        <div class="attachmentLoadContainer imgLoadContainer">
            <input type="hidden" class="attachment-input-name" value="AttachmentName" />
            <input type="hidden" class="attachment-original-input-name" value="AttachmentOrigName" />
            <input type="hidden" class="attachment-title-input-name" value="AttachmentTitle" />
            <div class="attachment-control image-control">
                <span>
                    <a class="delete-attachment-btn delete-image-btn" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a class="set-main-attachment-btn set-main-image-btn" href="#" %>">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a class="preview-attachment-btn preview-image-btn" href="#"%>">&nbsp;</a>
                </span>
                <a class="attachment-thumbnail image-thumbnail" href="JavaScript: return false;">
                    <img alt="ImageName" src="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="attachment-section photo-section">
    </div>
</div>
```

When i run my webApp i see that nothing renders in place where editor template html must be. I check it in debug mode - It go through editor template. Don't know why there is nothing.

---

**UPDATED :**

As @Stephen said, i try to update my editor to take 'collection' to prevent duplicate id's. 
So i add model

```
public class AttachmentsModel
    {
        public AttachmentsModel()
        {
            AttachmentList = new List<ListingAttachmentModel>();
        }

        public IList<ListingAttachmentModel> AttachmentList { get; set; }
    }
```

which contains list of elements, and now i pass it to editor. But just get from editor : 
`System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Models.Application.ListingAttachmentModel]`
Don't know why as i do similar things before

Comment: If `model.SpaceImages` is type of `ListingSpaceAttachmentModel` then you don't need (and should not be using) the `for` loop. It should be just `Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpaceImages)`. `EditorFor` will correctly render the collection. What do you expect to see? All you are rendering is a whole lot of hidden inputs (most which don't even have a name attribute so they are pointless) and a few links inside a hidden div. What are you expecting to achieve with this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `model.SpaceImages` is `List<ListingSpaceAttachmentModel>`. What I expect - Just Button 'Add' - it is button for image Uploader.

Comment: Check the html it renders. And replace the `for` loop with `Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpaceImages)` so the collection is rendered correctly (currently you have multiple duplicate ID's which is invalid html)

Comment: You said _i try to update my editor_. What do you mean? The model used by your `EditorTemplate` was previously correct, now you appear to have changed it to a List and changed the type so I have no idea what your doing.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, never mind, problem is fixed, i think. Now i pass the name of my custom editor so it's works. Thanks

Comment: That is also incorrect. Clearly you do not understand how editor templates work. If property `SpaceImages` is typeof `List<ListingSpaceAttachmentModel>`, then in the main view is should be `Html.EditorFor(m => m.SpaceImages)` (DO NOT USE PASS A NAME) and your editor template should be `ListingSpaceAttachmentModel` (NOT `List<ListingSpaceAttachmentModel>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, no. `SpaceImages` type is `AttachmentsModel` now.

Comment: Does not matter, the same concept applies.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, why `(DO NOT USE PASS A NAME)` ?

Comment: Because that will override the default behavior which will create inputs such as `<input name="[0].AttachmentId ..><input name="[1].AttachmentId ..>` i.e. correctly named with indexers for postback (and with unique ID's) and instead you will get `<input name="AttachmentId ..><input name="AttachmentId ..>` which will not bind to a collection on post back (and you will have duplicate ID's)